# convertir horario UTC a GMT

Tags: java, java-ee, java-8

Tengo un método en el que obtengo la fecha en String la convierto en tipo Date  pero quiero que ese horario que tengo convertirlo en horario GMT ya que la BD y la app esta instalada en un servidor de US y la fecha que obtengo es diferente a la de México por 5 horas aproximadamente.

utilizo el siguiente método.

```
public static String userDateGMT(String lastbind) throws ParseException {

    System.out.println("Fecha lastbind: " + lastbind); //2018-04-26 18:00:00

    if (lastbind != "") {

        SimpleDateFormat converter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        Date date = converter.parse(lastbind);
        System.out.println("Date UTC: " + date); 

        converter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
        System.out.println("Date GMT " + converter.format(date)); //2018-04-26 23:00:00
        String dategmt = converter.format(date);

        return dategmt; //deberia retornarme 2018-04-26 13:00:00
    }
    return "";
}
```

modifiqué esta linea:    converter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));

pero no me cambia el horario.

Comment: UTC y GMT suelen considerarse, para términos prácticos, iguales, aunque UTC es lo que debe utilizarse hoy. Es decir, si conviertes de UTC a GMT, vas a obtener la misma hora. https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiempo_universal_coordinado

Comment: ¿Has intentado con `TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Mexico_City")`?

Comment: @jachguate Excelente con: "America/Mexico_City" quedo sin problemas me hace los cambios de horario correctamente, gracias

Comment: Dejé una respuesta, para que no se pierda en comentarios. Un saludo.

Answer (score 1):

Tu problema está en que el tiempo UTC es, para efectos prácticos, el mismo que el GMT.

Para mostrar la hora equivalente en México, utiliza esa zona horaria, y no UTC.

```
converter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Mexico_City"));
```

Answer (score 0):

java 8 tiene un paquete nuevo para fechas, se llama java.time.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html

```
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.ZoneId;

public static String userDateGMT(String lastbind) throws ParseException {

  System.out.println("Fecha lastbind: " + lastbind); //2018-04-26 18:00:00

  if (lastbind == null || lastbind.isEmpty()) {
      return "";
  }
  //creamos el formato, probablemente fuera de esta método
  DateTimeFormatter formato = DateFormatter.ofPatter("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

  //obtenemos la hora y tiempo local de la cadena recibida
  LocalDateTime horaLocal = LocalDateTime.parse(lastbind, formato);

  //convertimos a instante para poder manejar zonas
  Instant instante = horaLocal.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant(); 

   //con este instante podemos cambiar la zona
  LocalDateTime horaGMT = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(instante, ZoneId.of("GMT")));

  //y la retornamos con el mismo formato
  return (horaGMT.format(formato));

}
```